# Pagination on job listing not working

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Links on pagination on job listing aren't working properly as they add a questionmark on the url instead of an ampersand

For example

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?location=holland&range=20&distanceUnits=Km?pg=1

instead of

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs?location=holland&range=20&distanceUnits=Km&pg=1

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the bug report! It should be fixed now.